# Django templates json loops

Tags: python, django

I use python/django views to get an output as:

```
{{ test }}
```

in my template. Here is the output

```
{'platform': 'xbox', 'amount': '50.00', 'title': 'title of something', 'description': 'description of something'}
```

If I use

```
{% for x in test %}
{{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

it outputs

```
platform, amount, title, description
```

How do I get the values and not the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just standard Python iteration over a dictionary, which defaults to iterating over the keys. If you want just the values, use `{% for x in test.values %}`. If you want key/value pairs, use `{% for k, v in test.items %}`.

Comment: Wow that was exactly what I was looking for!! So then if I have another array nested like this ([('master', {'foo': 'test', 'bar' {'key', {'anotherkey': 'value'}} how would I iterate through that?

Comment: I'll post another question that way I can really explain what I mean. Thank you very much. My confusion came from thinking that "items" was an actual value and not an identifier to tell python that its an array or what not.

Comment: Well, `items` is a method on dict objects that returns an iterable of the key/value pairs in the dict. Django template syntax allows dot references to no-argument methods, as we see here. It's not precisely the identifier for an array.

Comment: I see, so I cant post another question for another hour. Would you mind answering my other question?

Comment: Dear SO,

How do I iterate through nested objects in a json array?

Here is what I have. 

Template:

    {% for key, values in test.items %}
    {{key}}: {{values}}
    {% endfor %}

JSON:

    {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': {'key4': {'key5': {'key6': 'val6', 'key7': 'val7'}}}}

Output:

    key1: val1
    key2: val2
    key3: {'key4': {'key5': {'key6': 'val6'}}}

I was assuming I would just:

    {% for key, values in values.key3 %}

However key3 is actually 'pending-users', so I'm not sure if its rejecting it because the key is title with a '-'?

Comment: Not sure I have your full context in mind - are you still iterating through multiple key/value pairs? Detecting nested dicts in a Django template gets difficult or impossible, but if you always know the key its something like `{% if key == "pending-users" %}{% for subkey, subvalue in value.items %}...{% else %}...{% endif %}`. Or, if you just want to show that value, `test.pending-users.items` should work too.